# Connect existing Facebook likes to a New Facebook page using app_id or page_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, app-id

I own [this web page](http://www.statsskuld.se/) . In the start it did not have any facebook page, just a like button.

But now the site got over 1000 likes so I created a facebook page for it: www.facebook.com/Statsskuld

But the facebook page says 0 likes while I have over 1000 likes on the site. So I tried to  connect my site with the new facebook page I just created.

I went to the facebook insight page and tried to connect it.

I pressed the "insight for your website" and selected "Statsskuld" from the dropdown and was given this code that I added to the header:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="257510024400990" />
```

But it failed. Multiple times, I tried changing to these:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="statsskuld" />
<meta property="fb:site_id" content="Statsskuld" />
```

I also tried with my own personal ID number with the same result.

The error I get is: 
No admin data found at [root webpage](http://statsskuld.se/). Insights requires admin data at this root webpage for the specified URL statsskuld.se

I then tried to use the facebook developer debugger, which gave me an error that I sadly not fully understod:

Object at URL 'statsskuld.se' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '257510024400990' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

And thats where I'm stuck at.

I would really appreciate a bit of help, I have tried with multiple id combinations with (app_id, page_id, admins).

Comment: `257510024400990` can not be admin, because that is a Facebook page. Only user accounts can be admin.

Comment: Also, there's no way to copy likes from a URL to a Facebook Page, they're different entities and don't share likes